# Как задать значение смещения для строки при её форматировании

Tags: c#, строки, форматирование

```
String.Format("{0, value}", SomeText);

string TollTip = "-f <Name>";
string help = "Name of file";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0, -20}{1, -10}", TollTip, help));
```

Нужно на выходе получить некую таблицу[image: вот такая вот таблица]

При передачи очень большого текста в {0} получиться вот такое. Потому что не помещается в  20 символов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
string TollTip = "-f <Name>";
string help = "Very long String Long Long Long";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0, -20}{1, -10}", TollTip, help));
```

Comment: Что вам в итоге надо-то? Задать ширину для `SomeText` которая вычисляется во время работы программы или в переменную записать значение? При чем тут const? Ничего не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например

```
String.Format("{0, " + value.ToString() + "}", SomeText);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ меня удовлетворяет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`String.Format("{0}, {1}", SomeText, value);`

Comment: вы не поняли вопроса.

Comment: @BeHappy пожалуйста опишите подробно то что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: изменил вопрос.